# HTML/Javascript - How to stop YouTube video from playing in the background after clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using HTML, CSS and JS to make a kind of modal window with a video and a cross (X) to close the window. But I'm having trouble getting the actual video from stop playing after I click the cross. Here's how the window looks:

[image]

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Video</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   
        </style>
    </head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="thumbnail-img">
            <img src="img/img_test.PNG" alt="">
            <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="popup-modal">
            <iframe class="video" width="230" height="155" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/THfL_OI1qt4"
                title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0"
                allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                allowfullscreen></iframe>

            <div class="btnclose">
                <span class="l1"></span>
                <span class="l2"></span>
            </div>                
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS class:

```
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.thumbnail-img{
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #82b0d8;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.thumbnail-img img{
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.thumbnail-img i{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 60px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.thumbnail-img i:hover{
    background: rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


.popup-modal{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: #080808;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transform: scaleX(0);
}

.popup-modal iframe{
    width: 75%;
    height: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

.btnclose{
   position: absolute;
   right: 20px;
   top: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btnclose span{
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #fff;
    margin-top: 7px;

}

.btnclose span:first-child{
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.l1{
    transform: translateY(10px) rotate(45deg);
}

.l2{
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

JS code:

```
const play = document.querySelector(".fa-play");
const modalwindow = document.querySelector(".popup-modal");

play.onclick = function(){
    modalwindow.style.transform = "scaleX(1)";
}

modalwindow.onclick = function(){
    modalwindow.style.transform = "scaleX(0)";
}
```

Any idea how can I get the video to stop after clicking X?

Comment: You can set the iframe's src to an empty string

Comment: What do you mean? @ChrisG

Comment: Like `document.querySelector('popup-modal iframe').setAttribute('src', "");`

Answer (score 0):

Set `src` default to **about:blank** and add data attribute `data-src` with link of youtube video.

When you click on play add link from `data-src` to `src` attribute

And opposite when you click on close button add **about:blank** to `src` attribute.

```
<iframe class="video" width="230" height="155" src="about:blank" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/THfL_OI1qt4"
    title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0"
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
    allowfullscreen
></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks. You mean I should add the links in the JS code like this (I already changed the HTML code you sent): `play.onclick = function(){
    modalwindow.style.transform = "scaleX(1)";
    setAttribute('src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/THfL_OI1qt4"');
}

modalwindow.onclick = function(){
    modalwindow.style.transform = "scaleX(0)";
    setAttribute('data-src="about:blank"')
}
`